# Dekko legitimation error using IMAP

Tags: ubuntu-touch, imap

I installed Dekko on my brandnew Ubuntu Aquaris tablet and configured an IMAP account for my mailbox on Kabel Deutschland. Fortunately, the assistant stored the right settings but the connection fails with a legitimation error saying something about a problem with an underlaying socket and port 993. Has anyone any hints how to avoid the error?

Regards

Uwe

Comment: Please, could you add more details about the error you've got? It could help people to answer your question.